# Using component from imported module inside of child modules

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I have a module that export a component to expose it to other modules, I want to use this component in modules that are children of another module, I am importing the first module in the parent module to enable use inside of child modules but, I am not completely convinced that is the best way to do it.

This is my shared module in root folder with the component that I want to use:

**app/shared/shared.module.ts**

```
import {dtComponent} from './dt.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    dtComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    dtComponent
  ]
})
export class DatePModule{ }
```

I have another module in app folder that import **DatePModule** like this:

**app/contacts/contacts.module.ts**

```
import {DatePModule} from '../shared/shared.module.ts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DatePModule
  ]
})
export class CTModule{ }
```

I need to use **dtComponent** directly in some components of **CTModule**, but also need this component in other component that is in child modules of **CTModule**.

I can do it importing again **DatePModule** inside of child modules of **CTModule** but I am not convinced that is the best approach.

**app/contacts/other/other.module.ts**

```
import {DatePModule} from '../../shared/shared.module.ts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DatePModule
  ]
})
export class OtherModule{ }
```

My question is, why I need to import again **DatePModule** if is already imported in parent module? If I delete this import in **OtherModule** the component **dtComponent** is not recognized as a part of the module.

Comment: do you use lazy loading?

Comment: @Maximus yes I am using lazy loading to load all modules and components

Comment: well, my answer is still relevant, the shared and lazy loaded module will be merged and encapsulation resolved during merging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why I need to import again DatePModule if is already imported in
>   parent module

**There's no hierarchy between modules that you import into one another**. All modules are merged into one module definition factory with all components. If you use lazy-loading, still the same applies. The lazy-loaded module and shared module will be merged and there will be no hierarchy between them.

To learn more, read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f). Here is the quote:

> The biggest confusion regarding `imports` in modules is that
>   developers think it makes a hierarchy. And it’s probably reasonable
>   to assume that a module that imports other modules becomes the parent
>   module for its imports. However, that’s not what happens. All modules
>   are merged during compilation phase. And thus non-lazy loaded modules
>   do not create any hierarchy.

However, module `imports/exports` can enforce declarable types encapsulation **during compilation**. If you want to use declarable types from another module, you have to explicitly import this module or other module that re-exports the required module. The compiler controls encapsulation when parsing templates and the explicit imports provide the context to know that certain components can be used as children in the template.

> I can do it importing again DatePModule inside of child modules of
>   CTModule but I am not convinced that is the best approach.

That is correct approach if you want to use declarable types from `DatePModule` inside `OtherModule`.